# Why can't you access companion object of reified type parameter?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-reified-type-parameters

In the below, since `T` is reified, I want to use it ["almost as if it were a normal class"](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters) by accessing its companion object.

```
class Cls {
  companion object {
    fun method() { }
  }    
}

inline fun <reified T> func() {
  T.method()  // error
}

fun main() {
  func<Cls>()
}
```

But fails with

```
Type parameter 'T' cannot have or inherit a companion object, so it cannot be on the left hand side of dot
```

So it seems that a significant amount of information is lost. I get the same error with and without `reified`. I was hoping a `reified` type parameter would a fuller generic implementation than Java's. I have a ton of experience in C++ templates.

I've found some workarounds (that are all pretty disappointing using reflection), but really I'm asking *why* this can't work.

Comment: What would you even do with a companion object of a generic type if it were possible? You couldn't call `method()` like in your example because a `T` isn't a `Cls`?

Comment: @HenryTwist I want to take a protobuf Message and do `val message: T = T.getDefaultInstance()`, as an example. But there are plenty of reasons you'd want to invoke a static method / companion object method. `T` isn't _a_ `Cls`, `T` *is* `Cls`

Comment: I understand your use case. However I don't understand you saying that `T` is `Cls`. With the way you've declared `func`, it can take any type parameter, so I could call `func<String>`. Then `String` definitely wouldn't be a `Cls` and you couldn't guarantee that `String` has a companion object with a `method` function.

Comment: @HenryTwist It's `Cls` when you call `func<Cls>()` and it's `String` when you call `func<String>()`. Only the latter needs to fail to compile because the function is inlined in both calls. [The same example in C++](https://wandbox.org/permlink/05dgE3YPoYl4TFiB)

Comment: I think there's a misconception that `T` is `Cls`. The way you've wrote it `T` can be anything including `Cls`. Even if you let the compiler know that `T` will be a `Cls` by doing `<reified T : Cls>`, companion objects are not inherited. Maybe the problem is actually this, that companions are not inherited. Even if you would `class Foo : Cls()` you can never call `Foo.method()`. From your example it sounds more like you want an interface that has a method `getDefaultInstance`. Doesn't this fit your needs?

Comment: Right I see. Then I guess I want to know what kind of answer you expect. Kotlin just doesn't have this feature and to be honest it would break a lot of it's core principles if it did. I think your question is the same as asking why `Any a = "string"` wouldn't allow `a.substring(...)` for example. It doesn't really have anything to do with generics or inlining?

Comment: @Fred because the function is inlined, and you can do `v as T`, the type info is sticking around to a certain extent, unlike a non-inlined normal generic. An interface would work if this weren't a factory method.

Comment: @HenryTwist that's a great explanation of the shortcomings of Java's generics, and why you'd want `reified` types

Comment: I understand that Kotlin doesn't allow it, I'm still asking why the decision is what it is. It could be as straight-forward as "we didn't want to deal with the complexities of dependent expressions" I just wanna know what happened

Comment: It's a totally fair question. I actually don't know the answer but I'm also interested. I don't want to skew you from this, but I'm still not sure why interfaces don't work. Not saying let  `Cls` implement it, but create factories that implement this interface. I think then it should be simple to create a single factory that can can create any of these objects. It's more code for sure.

Comment: @Fred "why interfaces don't work" -> I didn't write the classes that I'm trying to use. Protobuf is set up this way (really with java static methods)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure this is answering all the questions, but it's too big for a comment.

First and as stated in the comments, the way the code is written, `T` is not necessarily a `Cls` so to allow this you'd need some changes:

```
open class Cls {
  companion object {
    fun method() { }
  }    
}

inline fun <reified T : Cls> func() {
  
}
```

*open the class and let Kotlin know `T` is a `Cls`*

However, even though it's inlined, this still wouldn't let you call the companion method because `T` has no companion. Even without generics:

```
open class Cls {
  companion object {
    fun method() { }
  }    
}

class Foo : Cls

fun main() = Foo.method() // doesn't work
```

Doesn't work because companions are not inherited. Why? It was a conscious decision by the Kotlin designers. As you know Kotlin aims to correct a lot of issues Java had and this was one.

Static methods in Java are bound at compile-time while overriding is based on dynamic binding at runtime. This becomes quite confusing when you mix both and Kotlin tried to avoid this. Here's an example:

```
class Cls {
    public static void method() {
        System.out.println("Cls' method");
    }
}

class Foo extends Cls {
    public static void method() {
        System.out.println("Foo's method");
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cls parent = new Foo();
        parent.method();
    }
}
```

If `method` would truly be overridden it would print out `Foo's method`, but indeed this prints `Cls' method`. The reason is that there's no overriding, but there's shadowing happening. On the other hand, if the methods wouldn't be static, then you'd get `Foo's method` since it is indeed overridden. This apparently caused confusion amongst developers and Kotlin completely disallowed it.