# A Kotlin Serializer for Generic Custom Lists

Tags: kotlin, generics, serialization, reification

In many Kotlin projects, I am using the `NonEmptyList` from arrow-kt for improved type safety. A problem arises when I want to serialize and deserialize such lists.

My attempt at a generic custom serializer with delegation does not seem to work:

```kotlin
class NonEmptyListSerializer<T: Serializable>() : KSerializer<NonEmptyList<T>> {
    private val delegatedSerializer = ListSerializer(T::class.serializer())

    @OptIn(ExperimentalSerializationApi::class)
    override val descriptor = SerialDescriptor("NonEmptyList", delegatedSerializer.descriptor)

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: NonEmptyList<T>) {
        val l = value.toList()
        encoder.encodeSerializableValue(delegatedSerializer, l)
    }

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): NonEmptyList<T> {
        val l = decoder.decodeSerializableValue(delegatedSerializer)
        return NonEmptyList.fromListUnsafe(l)
    }
}
```

The problem is that I cannot create the `delegatedSerializer` from the type parameter `T`, because type information is erased. Reification does not work for classes. Is there any possibility to access the serializer of the list's base object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I got it working:

```kotlin
class NonEmptyListSerializer<T>(baseTypeSerializer: KSerializer<T>) : KSerializer<NonEmptyList<T>> {
    private val delegatedSerializer = ListSerializer(baseTypeSerializer)

    @OptIn(ExperimentalSerializationApi::class)
    override val descriptor = SerialDescriptor("EnergyTimeSeries", delegatedSerializer.descriptor)

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: NonEmptyList<T>) {
        val l = value.toList()
        encoder.encodeSerializableValue(delegatedSerializer, l)
    }

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): NonEmptyList<T> {
        val l = decoder.decodeSerializableValue(delegatedSerializer)
        return l.toNonEmptyListOrNull() ?: throw IndexOutOfBoundsException("Nonempty list to be deserialized is empty")
    }
}
```

The trick is to pass in the base type serializer as constructor parameter. When annotating a type with `@Serializable(with = NonEmptyListSerializer::class)`, the serialization plugin seems to automatically provides the correct paramter. I am using Kotlin 1.7.20; not sure if it works also for older Kotlin releases.

Could someone explain exactly why the solution works?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a companion object with an `inline operator fun invoke` to create a pseudo-constructor with a reified type parameter.

```kotlin
class NonEmptyListSerializer<T : Serializable>(
    val delegatedSerializer: SerialDescriptor
) : KSerializer<NonEmptyList<T>> {

    companion object {
       inline operator fun <reified T> invoke() = NonEmptyListSerializer(ListSerializer(T::class.serializer()))
    }
    
    override val descriptor = SerialDescriptor("NonEmptyList", delegatedSerializer.descriptor)

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: NonEmptyList<T>) {
        val l = value.toList()
        encoder.encodeSerializableValue(delegatedSerializer, l)
    }

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): NonEmptyList<T> {
        val l = decoder.decodeSerializableValue(delegatedSerializer)
        return NonEmptyList.fromListUnsafe(l)
    }

}
```

Comment: Hm, this does not seem to compile. Meanwhile, I came across [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67321882/4090111), which seems to imply that I simply cannot obtain the desired serializer: The method `<KSerializer>.serializer()` is part of the companion object that is auto-generated by the Kotlin serialization pluging. Companion objects cannot be inherited and this are not accessible from type parameters.